# Program Tulip doesn't start after installing trough Software Center

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install tulip on my Ubuntu 15.10; When I install it trough Software Center, tulip just doesn't start; If I run it in terminal, it returns

`tulip: error while loading shared libraries: libbfd-2.25-system.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`

I tried installing for source too, but then i couldn't satisfy the dependencies and couldn't even build it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - Lubuntu 15.10 and Tulip doesn't start. Assuming your default Tulip installation is in `/usr/bin/Tulip`, you can check for missing dependencies using `ldd /usr/bin/Tulip`.

When `libbfd-2.25-system.so` is missing, install the `binutils` package using `sudo apt-get install binutils`. The package provides `libbfd-2.25.1-system.so`. Afterwards create a symbolic link with `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libbfd-2.25.1-system.so /usr/lib/libbfd-2.25-system.so`.

When you check Tulip again with `ldd`, the missing dependency should be gone and Tulip starts! At least that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Works in Ubuntu 18.04: download the [AppImage Tulip file](https://sourceforge.net/projects/auber/files/tulip/tulip-5.3.1/), make it executable, Tulip runs like a charm